'user_role' plugin is missing?
I used composer to update Drupal core and all dependencies to 10.3 and have run into some trouble with "an unexpected error." I went to restore the existing site and the database backup folder is.... missing.
So I went down a rabbit hole and used system.logging to get to an error message about Bootstrap which led me to (https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3452819) - I updated to bootstrap 3.31 using composer. Did update.php and rebooted the server.
But now I have a new error and I can not make head or tail of what I have done or how I could fix it? Does anyone have any ideas? Googling it all suggests that user_roles is a function, but how could I have removed a function?
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "user_role" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\rules\Core\ConditionManager are: rules_entity_has_field, rules_user_has_role, rules_data_comparison, rules_node_is_of_type, rules_entity_is_new, rules_text_comparison, rules_data_is_empty, rules_node_is_promoted, rules_node_is_sticky, rules_path_has_alias, rules_entity_is_of_bundle, rules_path_alias_exists, rules_list_count_is, rules_user_is_blocked, rules_entity_field_access, rules_list_contains, rules_node_is_published, rules_entity_is_of_type, webform, civicrm_contact_id_drupal_user_exists, civicrm_entity_drupal_user_exists, civicrm_entity_contact_in_group in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition() (Line: 16)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionManager->createInstance() (Line: 21)
Drupal\rules\Core\ConditionManager->createInstance() (Line: 81)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultLazyPluginCollection->initializePlugin() (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get() (Line: 26)
Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionPluginCollection->get() (Line: 149)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->getIterator() (Line: 88)
Drupal\block\BlockAccessControlHandler->checkAccess() (Line: 109)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler->access() (Line: 329)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->access() (Line: 63)
Drupal\block\BlockRepository->getVisibleBlocksPerRegion() (Line: 138)
Drupal\block\Plugin\DisplayVariant\BlockPageVariant->build() (Line: 270)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare() (Line: 128)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse() (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray()
call_user_func() (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 186)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 53)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 191)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->fetch() (Line: 128)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->lookup() (Line: 82)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 36)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 741)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)


user_role is a core plugin that still exists in Drupal 10.3. The problem is that you have the Rules module installed which had replaced the annotation-based plugin discovery and core switched to PHP Attributes. Now the Rules module can't find the core plugins anymore. In this issue are tips on how to recover the site https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/3454056
BTW the Rules module is still an alpha version. Don't update a production site containing alpha versions without testing the update locally.
